# Comparators sorting

Tags: java, string, sorting, comparator

I'm not good with comparators but I need to learn it, I've done this much so far but I keep getting error at 'System.out.println(compy("January", "March", "October", "April"));'... please help, I would like an explanation with a fix. Thank You!

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Months {
    public static void main (String args[]){

        System.out.println(Comp("January","May"));
        System.out.println(Comp("October", "May"));
        System.out.println(Comp("August","August"));
        System.out.println(Comp("January", "March"));

        System.out.println(compy("January", "March", "October", "April"));
    }

    static int Comp(String s1, String s2){

        while (true){
            int r = 0;
            int s = 0;

            if(s1.equals("January")){
                r=1;
            }

            if(s1.equals("February")){
                r=2;
            }

            if(s1.equals("March")){
                r=3;
            }

            if(s1.equals("April")){
                r=4;
            }

            if(s1.equals("May")){
                r=5;
            }

            if(s1.equals("June")){
                r=6;
            }

            if(s1.equals("July")){
                r=7;
            } 

            if(s1.equals("August")){
                r=8;
            }

            if(s1.equals("September")){
                r=9;
            }

            if(s1.equals("October")){
                r=10;
            }

            if(s1.equals("November")){
                r=11;
            }

            if(s1.equals("December")){
                r=12;
            }

            if(s2.equals("January")){
                s=1;
            }

            if(s2.equals("February")){
                s=2;
            }

            if(s2.equals("March")){
                s=3;
            }

            if(s2.equals("April")){
                s=4;
            }

            if(s2.equals("May")){
                s=5;
            }

            if(s2.equals("June")){
                s=6;
            }

            if(s2.equals("July")){
                s=7;
            }

            if(s2.equals("August")){
                s=8;
            }

            if(s2.equals("September")){
                s=9;
            }

            if(s2.equals("October")){
                s=10;
            }

            if(s2.equals("November")){
                s=11;
            }

            if(s2.equals("December")){
                s=12;
            }

            if(r<s){
                return -1;
            }

            if(r>s){
                return 1;
            }
            if(r==s){
                return 0;
            }

        }   

    }

    public class Comp implements Comparator {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2){
            return Comp((String)o1, (String)o2);
        }
    }

    void sort(List l){
        Comparator compy = new Comp();
        Collections.sort(l, compy);
    }

}
```

Comment: your method `Comp` should be renamed `comp`. In java, method names start with a lowercase letter, followed by uppercase for following words by convention. I don't think that's the error, but it sure confuses me.

Comment: BTW, use arrays and `indexOf()`.

Comment: And enums might be helpful.

Comment: Where are you actually _calling_ the sort method (which creates the compy object your code can't find)?

Comment: What is `compy`? I see a variable by that name in the method `sort`, but that variable is not visible in `main`. Even if it was, `compy("January", "March", "October", "April"))` is bad syntax.

Comment: This is not good way to learn Java. Download this  http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/ and read the corresponding chapters. Eventually, read the whole book. :)

Comment: There are a number of problems with this code. You have a static method and a class with the same name, a method which creates this compy which you never reference and a return statement for your compare which doesn't make a lot of sense. Start over and go slower and build up bit by bit.

Comment: I would back up a little and do some reading before writing any more code: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can sort a list with your code.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("March");
list.add("January");
list.add("October");
list.add("April");

System.out.println("Before sort: " + list);
// prints: Before sort: [March, January, October, April]

new Months().sort(list); // sort

System.out.println("After sort: " + list);
// prints: After sort: [January, March, April, October]
```

Comment: @AndrewMartin in fact, I would replace the whole implementation of the comparator per one that uses a `Map<Integer, String> map` where the map stores each month and it's *key*.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Better still!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, there are more issues with OP's code but my sole focus was on how OP can sort with **his** code. @AndrewMartin, JDK 8 comes with a `java.time.Month` Enum. That would be hundred times better. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ravi Thapliyal gave you good solution, but if i can suggest something, change your comparator

```
public class Comp implements Comparator<String> {

   private List<String> months = Arrays.asList("January" , "February",...);

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return months.indexOf(s1)-months.indexOf(s2);
    }
}
```

its much shorter and more readable

Answer (score 0):

Including the actual error would help.

It looks to me like the error is you are compy a variable in the sort method.  from the main method.

Try something like

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeWork {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    MonthComparable compy = new MonthComparable();
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"May", "June", "April"});
    Collections.sort(myList, compy);
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static class MonthComparable implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String left, String right) {
      Integer leftValue = monthValue(left);
      Integer rightValue = monthValue(right);
      return leftValue.compareTo(rightValue);
    }

    private static int monthValue(String left) {
      // TODO Implement this
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the content of your response is better suited as a comment than an answer.  i realize you might not have comment rights yet, though.